# Sort an antd (Ant Design) table that has selection enabled

Tags: javascript, reactjs, sorting, react-redux, antd

I am trying to make a [table with antd](https://ant.design/components/table/) that allows sorting and row selection (using checkboxes).

Right now I have both enabled, however, when I sort by ascending/descending order, the selection does not sort. The checked boxes just stay at the same index as before.

To fix this I tried making a custom sort function that could possibly sort the `selectedRowKeys` the same way it is sorting the table rows, but I am not able to retrieve the information I need in the callback function to do this.

Has anyone ever done this before?

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Related, but not a duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59479703/cant-sort-column-in-ant-design-table-in-gatsby-site

Answer (score 1):

You have not set the key of rows.
You have two ways to do it:

- in the objects of the columns array add the `key` properties (with a property that represents a row identifier)
- set `rowKey` props for the table with the name of the property that represents a row identifier in the columns objects